# Problema na atualização da janela em tempo real

Tags: python, tkinter

Olá. Estou a criar um programa que permite ao usuário saber qual nota está a cantar e a sua respetiva frequência, em tempo real. No entanto, durante a atualização da janela, o programa deixa de funcionar e só atualiza ao fim de alguns segundos, acontecendo várias vezes ao longo da execução do programa. Código:

```
    # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from numba import jit
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import sys
from audiolazy import (tostream, AudioIO, freq2str, sHz, chunks, lowpass, envelope, pi, thub, Stream, maverage)
from numpy.fft import rfft
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ttk
import pyaudio
import pylab
import random

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#funcoes de calculo do pitch--------------------------------------------------#

#variaveis do pyaudio
f_a=440.0

chunk=2048
FORMAT=pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS=1
RATE=44100
RECORD_S=2.
WAVE_OUTPUT_NAME="sing.wav"


pa=pyaudio.PyAudio()



# pylab.ioff()
stream=pa.open(format=FORMAT,
             channels=CHANNELS,
             rate=RATE,
             input=True,
             frames_per_buffer=chunk)

#calcula a frequencia 
def real_freq():
    all_v=[]
    all_data=""
    x_array=numpy.array([],dtype=numpy.int16)
    n_chunks=int(RECORD_S*RATE/chunk)
    npts=n_chunks*chunk

    for i in range(0, n_chunks):
        try:
            data=stream.read(chunk)
        except:
            data=stream.read(chunk)
        all_v.append(data)
        all_data += data
        x=numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=numpy.int16)
        numpy.append(x_array,x)

    all_x=numpy.fromstring(all_data, dtype=numpy.int16)

    #p2p = 2.*numpy.sqrt(2.*all_x.var())

    z = abs(pylab.fft(all_x))
    max_arg = numpy.argmax(z[0:npts/2])
    #peak = z[max_arg]   

    freq = pylab.arange(npts)*1.*RATE/npts
    fmax = freq[max_arg] + 0.01
    fmax = round(fmax, 2)
    return fmax


def limiter(sig, threshold=.1, size=256, env=envelope.rms, cutoff=pi/2048):
    sig = thub(sig, 2)
    return sig * Stream( 1. if el <= threshold else threshold / el for el in maverage(size)(env(sig, cutoff=cutoff)) )

@tostream
def dft_pitch(sig, size=2048, hop=None):
    for blk in Stream(sig).blocks(size=size, hop=hop):
        dft_data = rfft(blk)
        idx, vmax = max(enumerate(dft_data), key=lambda el: abs(el[1]) / (2 * el[0] / size + 1))
        yield 2 * pi * idx / size

def pitch_from_mic(upd_time_in_ms):
    rate = 44100
    s, Hz = sHz(rate)

    api = sys.argv[1] if sys.argv[1:] else None # Choose API via command-line
    chunks.size = 1 if api == "jack" else 16

    with AudioIO(api) as recorder:
        snd = recorder.record(rate=rate)
        sndlow = lowpass(400 * Hz)(limiter(snd, cutoff=20 * Hz))
        hop = int(upd_time_in_ms * 1e-3 * s)
        for pitch in freq2str(dft_pitch(sndlow, size=2*hop, hop=hop) / Hz):
            first_cut = pitch.find('+')
            second_cut = pitch.find('-')
            if ((first_cut != -1) and (second_cut == -1)):
                yield pitch[0:first_cut]
            elif ((first_cut == -1) and (second_cut != -1)):
                yield pitch[0:second_cut]

#funcao que define a afinacao (semelhante com a funcao pitch_from_mic())
def pitch_tune(upd_time_in_ms):
    #calcula o pitch
    rate = 44100
    s, Hz = sHz(rate)

    api = sys.argv[1] if sys.argv[1:] else None # Choose API via command-line
    chunks.size = 1 if api == "jack" else 16

    with AudioIO(api) as recorder:
        snd = recorder.record(rate=rate)
        sndlow = lowpass(400 * Hz)(limiter(snd, cutoff=20 * Hz))
        hop = int(upd_time_in_ms * 1e-3 * s)

        #calculado o pitch, le o valor encontrado e retorna a afinacao
        for tune in freq2str(dft_pitch(sndlow, size=2*hop, hop=hop) / Hz):
            first_cut = tune.find('+')
            second_cut = tune.find('-')
            third_cut = tune.find('%')
            if ((first_cut != -1) and (second_cut == -1)):
                fourth_cut = tune[first_cut:third_cut]
                flat_one = fourth_cut[1:]
                flat_one = float(flat_one)

               #le os valores e retorna a afinacao
                if (flat_one <= 20):
                    yield 'Afinado'
                elif ((flat_one > 20) and (flat_one <= 35)):
                    yield 'Lig. Desafinado'
                elif (flat_one > 35):
                    yield 'Muito Desafinado'              
            elif ((first_cut == -1) and (second_cut != -1)):
                fifth_cut = tune[second_cut:third_cut]
                flat_two = fifth_cut[1:]
                flat_two = float(flat_two)
                #le os valores e retorna a afinacao
                if (flat_two <= 20):
                    yield 'Afinado'
                elif ((flat_two > 20) and (flat_two <= 35)):
                    yield 'Lig. Desafinado'
                elif (flat_two > 35):
                    yield 'Muito Desafinado'

# ----------------------
#Parte grafica do codigo
# ----------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from Tkinter import *
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
    import threading
    import re

    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

    #comeca a janela do programa
    root = Tk()

    #define o tamanho da janela
    root.minsize(1200,500)
    root.maxsize(1200,500)
    root.configure(background='#d9d9d9')
    root.focus_force()

    #titulo da janela (outer widget)
    root.title("SingMeter")

    #stringvars
    pitch_value = StringVar()
    note_value = StringVar()
    no_tone_deaf = StringVar()

   #-----Frames secundaria(outer widgets)
    #frame do pitch
    sing_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='Informacão quantitativa', width=400, height=400, background='#d9d9d9')
    sing_frame.place(x = 10, y = 30)

    #frame da nota
    graph_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='Gráfico', width=700, height=400, background='#d9d9d9')
    graph_frame.place(x = 450, y = 30)

    #listas e dicionarios de frequencias e notas (torna a base de dados propia para leitura)
    database_dict = {}
    freq_list = []

    #funcoes do grafico-------------------------------------------------------#

    xAchse=pylab.arange(0,100,1)
    yAchse=pylab.array([0]*100)

    fig = pylab.figure(1)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_xlabel("Tempo")
    ax.set_ylabel("Frequência")
    ax.axis([0,100, 50, 2000])
    line1=ax.plot(xAchse,yAchse,'-')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = graph_frame)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 100, y = 50)

    canvas._tkcanvas.place(x = 100, y = 25)

    values=[]
    values = [0 for x in range(100)]

    Ta=0.01
    fa=1.0/Ta
    fcos=3.5

    Konstant=1
    T0=1.0
    T1=Konstant

    freq_list = []

    def SinwaveformGenerator():
      global values,T1,Konstant,T0,wScale2
      #ohmegaCos=arccos(T1)/Ta
      #print "fcos=", ohmegaCos/(2*pi), "Hz"

      Tnext=((Konstant*T1)*2)-T0 
      if (len(values)%100>70):
          try:
              values.append(random.random())
          except:
              raise
      else:
          values.append(Tnext)
      T0=T1
      T1=Tnext
      root.after(int(wScale2['to'])-wScale2.get(),SinwaveformGenerator)

    def RealtimePloter():
      global values,wScale,wScale2
      NumberSamples=min(len(values),wScale.get())
      CurrentXAxis=pylab.arange(len(values)-NumberSamples,len(values),1)
      line1[0].set_data(CurrentXAxis,pylab.array(values[-NumberSamples:]))
      ax.axis([CurrentXAxis.min(),CurrentXAxis.max(),50, 2000])
      canvas.draw()
      root.after(25,RealtimePloter)
      #canvas.draw()

      #manager.show()    

    wScale = Scale(master=root,label="View Width:", from_=3, to=1000,sliderlength=30, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    wScale2 = Scale(master=root,label="Generation Speed:", from_=1, to=200,sliderlength=30, orient=HORIZONTAL)

    wScale.set(100)
    wScale2.set(wScale2['to']-10)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #fecha a janela
    def _quit():
        root.quit()    
        root.destroy()

    #funcões com elementos (inner widgets) da janela
    @jit
    def entries_window(pitch, note, sing_state):
        #exibidor do pitch
        pitch_value.set(pitch)
        show_pitch = ttk.Entry(sing_frame, textvariable = pitch_value, state = 'readonly')
        show_pitch.place(x = 120, y = 58.5)

        #exibidor da nota
        note_value.set(note)
        show_note = ttk.Entry(sing_frame, textvariable = note_value, state = 'readonly')
        show_note.place(x = 120, y = 135)

        #exibidor da performance das notas do cantor
        no_tone_deaf.set(sing_state)
        show_tone_deaf = ttk.Entry(sing_frame, textvariable = no_tone_deaf, state = 'readonly')
        show_tone_deaf.place(x = 170, y = 211.5)
    entries_window(None, None, None)

    #@jit
    def window():
        #labels
        #label PITCH
        pitch_title = ttk.Label(sing_frame, text = "Pitch:", font = "Verdana 20", background='#d9d9d9')
        pitch_title.place(x = 30, y = 50)

        #label NOTE
        note_title = ttk.Label(sing_frame, text = "Nota:", font = "Verdana 21", background='#d9d9d9')
        note_title.place(x = 30, y = 126)

        #label AFINACAO
        tune_title = ttk.Label(sing_frame, text = "Afinação", font = "Verdana 21", background='#d9d9d9')
        tune_title.place(x = 30, y = 202)
        #------------------------

        #botões
        #botao SAIR
        record = ttk.Button(sing_frame, text = 'Sair', command=_quit) 
        record.place(x = 70, y = 300)

        """#botao STOP
        stop_button = ttk.Button(sing_frame, text = 'Parar')
        stop_button.place(x = 160, y = 300)"""
    window()


    regex_note = re.compile(r"^([A-Gb#]*-?[0-9]*)([?+-]?)(.*?%?)$")
    upd_time_in_ms = 200

    # atualiza as funcoes
    def upd_value():
        pitches = iter(pitch_from_mic(upd_time_in_ms))
        while not root.should_finish:
            root.value = next(pitches)

    #atualiza os valores da janela
    #@jit
    def upd_timer(): 
        note_value.set("\n".join(regex_note.findall(root.value)[0]))
        tunes = iter(pitch_tune(upd_time_in_ms))
        tuning = next(tunes)
        no_tone_deaf.set(str("\n".join(regex_note.findall(tuning)[0])))
        pitch_value.set(real_freq())
        root.after(upd_time_in_ms, upd_timer)
        root.after(1, SinwaveformGenerator)
        root.after(1 ,RealtimePloter)

    # inicia as threads
    root.should_finish = False
    root.value = freq2str(0)
    note_value.set(root.value)
    root.upd_thread = threading.Thread(target=upd_value)


    #acaba o programa e as threads
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _quit)
    root.after_idle(upd_timer)
    root.upd_thread.start()
    root.mainloop()
    root.should_finish = True
    root.upd_thread.join()
```

Tentei usar o numba (`from numba import jit`) e o Cython para melhorar o desempenho da execução do programa, mas não tive melhorias significativas. Tentei ainda usar o PyPy, mas devido à sua incompatibilidade com o Numpy não consegui executar o código. As funções `pitch_from_mic(upd_time_in_ms)` e `pitch_tune(upd_time_in_ms)` calculam a nota da mesma forma (não consegui colocar toda esta parte do código numa única função, pois dava o seguinte erro: `IOError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed`). A função `real_freq()` demora algum tempo a calcular a frequência, mas, se não forem chamadas as outras funções, o código possui um desempenho aceitável. Estou a usar o Windows 7 e tenho o Python 2.7.8.

Comment: Que janela? O que é deixar de funcionar?

Comment: O programa deixa de exibir os valores da frequência e da nota e encrava (e impede-me de fechar a janela).  Passados alguns segundos, o programa volta ao normal, mas volta a encravar ao fim de mais alguns segundos.

Comment: Provavelmente é porque você está rodando os algoritmos na mesma Thread da interface Gráfica.

Comment: Mas de que forma os consigo separar, tendo em conta que os algoritmos necessitam de ser constantemente executados e que a janela precisa de ser atualizada regularmente?

Comment: dei uma rápida olhada no código, existem funções para cálculo de pitch redundantes, vc praticamente faz duas coisas iguais ao mesmo tempo, sem falar que usar Fourier e só encontrar o valor máximo da magnitude não te dará resultados confiáveis dependendo do tipo de sinal analisado, sua janela de análise tbm parece ser muito pequena, isso poderia ser melhorado para conseguir resultados mais robustos ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, para criar uma interface gráfica é usada uma Thread principal que cuida da atualização da interface e outra(s) thread(s) que executam as outras partes do código em paralelo.

Dito isso, a implementação mais comum do python(CPython) utiliza um mecanismo( chamado GIL) para sincronizar as threads que não permite que duas threads executem código python simultaneamente.

Para resolver o seu problema, você precisará criar um processo (com o modulo [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)) que executará os cálculos em segundo plano e passar para a thread gráfica os valores a serem exibidos com algum mecanismo disponível no modulo(por exemplo uma [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes))